# Solve recursion and infinite loop issue

Tags: c#, recursion, infinite-loop

I am currently writing a program which reads data in from a text file. The problem I am currently having is that the CompareTo method below is coming up with the error `System.StackOverflowException was unhandled` and saying "Make sure you don't have an infinite loop or infinite recursion. This error appears on the line `return name.CompareTo(temp.name);`.

The whole class is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Country
{
    public class Country : IComparable
    {
        // Country Properties

        private String name;
        private float gdpGrowth;
        private float inflation;
        private float tradeBalance;
        private float hdiRanking;
        private LinkedList<String> tradePartners;

        //Constructor

        public Country(String name, float gdpGrowth, float inflation, float tradeBalance, float hdiRanking, LinkedList<String> tradePartners)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.gdpGrowth = gdpGrowth;
            this.inflation = inflation;
            this.tradeBalance = tradeBalance;
            this.hdiRanking = hdiRanking;
            this.tradePartners = tradePartners;
        }

        public String Name
        {
            set { this.name = value; }
            get { return name; }
        }

        public float GdpGrowth
        {
            set { this.gdpGrowth = value; }
            get { return gdpGrowth; }
        }

        public float Inflation
        {
            set { this.inflation = value; }
            get { return inflation; }
        }

        public float TradeBalance
        {
            set { this.tradeBalance = value; }
            get { return tradeBalance; }
        }

        public float HdiRankings
        {
            set { this.hdiRanking = value; }
            get { return hdiRanking; }
        }

        public LinkedList<String> TradePartners
        {
            set { this.tradePartners = value; }
            get { return tradePartners; }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return name + ", " + gdpGrowth + ", " + inflation + ", " + tradeBalance + ", " + hdiRanking + ", " + tradePartners;
        }

        public int CompareTo(object other)
        {                
            Country temp = (Country)other;
            return name.CompareTo(temp.name);
        }    
    }
}
```

The class which is calling the country class is...

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Country
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private AVLTree<Country> countryTree = new AVLTree<Country>();




        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // array to stroe each line of the file
            String[] Lines = new string[1000];
            String[] tempPartners = new string[1000];

            int count = 0;

            // Store each line of the file in the eachLine array

            Lines = File.ReadAllLines("countries.csv");

            foreach (String line in Lines)
            {
                if (count == 0)
                {
                    count++;
                }
                else
                {
                    // array to hold info
                    String[] info = new string[5];
                    //splits the countries
                    info = line.Split(',');
                    // split trade partners and puts in array
                    tempPartners = info[5].Split(';', '[', ']');
                    // insert current instance of country into AVL Tree
                    countryTree.InsertItem(new Country(info[0], float.Parse(info[1]), 
                    float.Parse(info[2]), float.Parse(info[3]), float.Parse(info[4]), new LinkedList<String>(tempPartners)));


                    // create seperator 
                    string seperator = ", ";
                    // stroe array
                    string partners = string.Join(seperator, tempPartners);
                    // remove first comma
                    partners = partners.Substring(1, partners.Length - 1);
                    //remove last comma
                    partners = partners.Remove(partners.Length - 2);
                    //pass in information from file into grid view
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(info[0], info[1], info[2], info[3], info[4], partners);

                }
            }
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the class declaration.  Why are you calling name.CompareTo()?  That is the problem.

Comment: If your CompareTo calls CompareTo which calls CompareTo which then calls ... and so on, it seems pretty obvious?

Comment: Yeah we don't have the full code. I think your problem though is your CompareTo statement that matches the signature of what you're calling inside the CompareTo statement. You need to do something like base.CompareTo instead of what you're calling there (which is itself)

Comment: @ThomasTaylor but isn't `name` from `name.CompareTo()` a string?

Comment: @CyberDude `name` could be something that has an implicit cast defined to and from `string`.  Unlikely, but in the end we need to see more of this class.

Comment: This would go by a lot quicker if you posted the entire class :)

Comment: Replacing that line with `String.Compare(name, temp.name)` would make sure a string comparison is used

Comment: This doesn't address your problem, but I'd avoid using `Country temp = (Country)other;` - you're better off with `Country temp = other as Country; if ( temp != null )...`. This will avoid an invalid cast exception.

Comment: Apologies i didn't think the whole class was needed, I have now included the whole class, thanks

Comment: @AdamLuke26: Could you please provide the code that's using the Country class?

Comment: We need to see the what's calling this method...

Comment: The added code never calls `CompareTo()`...we need to see where your `CompareTo` is called externally.

Comment: Also, your `CompareTo` has a high chance to cause a InvalidCastException

Answer (score 1):

You've got infinite recursion going here. `CompareTo` makes a recursive call but doesn't terminate due to the lack of a base case, so the recursive stack grows infinite. No actual comparison takes place either. What integer values do you want this to return, and under what conditions?

Perhaps as CyberDude said, you're really trying to use `String.Compare(name, temp.name)`?